# Problems entering more than one information in the textbox using enter

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to c# and I'm trying to make a specific calculator, to calculate the total seals for a job, but I'm having a problem I can't make it every time I enter a value in a textbox and price enter it save the value and clear the textbox.

I've tried several ways to use enter and one worked but the cycle wouldn't stop, I've also tried to make the code in several ways, I made this calculator in a console app and it worked, but now I wanted to move to something more beautiful and easier reading.

This is my code:

```
private void Ctext_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (cv == 0)
    {
        c = float.Parse(Ctext.Text);
        ml = c;
        postint = (c / 3);
        postint = (float)Math.Floor(postint);
        totalpostint = postint - 1;
        Reslb.Text = Convert.ToString(totalpostint);
        Reslb2.Text = Convert.ToString(ml);
        if (c > 50)
        {
            Reflb.Visible = true;
            Reftext.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cv > 0)
        {
            if (arrsimbox.Checked)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i >= cv; i = i + 1)
                    {
                        c = float.Parse(Ctext.Text);
                        postint = c / 3;
                        postint = (float)Math.Floor(postint) - 1;
                        totalpostint = totalpostint + postint;
                        ml = ml + c;
                        Ctext.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's something weird: `for(int i=0; i>=cv; i=i+1)` but you're in the branch where `cv>0` so you can never loop. Also if for some reason you **could** loop, having `i>=cv` and `i=i+1` would make it an *infinite loop* (as you increase `i`, you would never break out of the loop) --> should probably be `i<=cv` instead of `i>=cv`

Comment: The problem is this is not a common calculate like for example the windows itself. But thanks, I'll try to find some, maybe I can get some more information.

Comment: @Rafalon Did you see any more errors?

Comment: @JorgeLopes No I didn't. Those were the most obvious as I didn't need to understand the purpose of your program in order to determine that this behaviour (loop which can't be entered & infinite loop) is highly likely to be unexpected. For the rest, as I have no idea of what is expected, I can't say anything.

Comment: @Rafalon Basically I have a textbox to insert how many corners the fence has, if it has corners then it will make the checkbox visible and after selecting one of the checkbox we reach this point that I would be in a single textbox I wanted to insert several measures and it enters the loop to saving the value performed the operations and then cleared the textbox to be able to insert more values ​​until the i was equal to the number of corners

Comment: Oh right, then you need to get rid of that loop. The point is, you already have a value `cv`, you need to have another counter (let's say `curCorner`) and whenever your user presses enter, you check if `curCorner<cv`, then you store the value, increment `curCorner` and clear text. Done

Comment: @Rafalon But for that I don't need to use the for or while loop?

Comment: No you don't, the function will be re-entered on key press. If you loop *inside* the function, you are not letting the user enter any more value

Comment: @Rafalon I removed the for loop and put the counter this way, but even so it is infinite and does not update the counter is 1 and goes down to 0. I apologize for being annoying.
`int countconners = 0;
if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter)) 
{
if (countconners < cv)
{
}
countconners = countconners + 1;
}`

Comment: You are not annoying. Please make sure you set `int countcorners = 0;` **outside** the function, so you're not resetting to `0` at every key press. You should also think about a way to reset it to `0` on demand (or whenever you change the `cv` value)

Comment: @Rafalon Thank you very much for your help, it worked now I just need to improve. How can I mark your answer?

Comment: I added an answer with the points above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal, I would add a counter to keep track of what value is being entered (first, second, third... until you reach the `cv` value).
I'd get rid of any loop (as it would only prevent user from enter any other value), and let the function get called again when needed.

```
// counter declared and set outside function so it doesn't get reset everytime
int countcorners = 0;

private void Ctext_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
    {
        if (countcorners < cv)
        {
            // get the value
            c = float.Parse(Ctext.Text);
            // do calculations
            postint = c / 3;
            postint = (float)Math.Floor(postint) - 1;
            totalpostint = totalpostint + postint;
            ml = ml + c;
            // clear textbox
            Ctext.Clear();
            // increment counter (shortcut for "countcorners = countcorners + 1;")
            countcorners++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

To go further, I wouldn't parse the value this way, but rather like:

```
// c = float.Parse(Ctext.Text);
if (float.TryParse(Ctext.Text, out c))
{
    // do calculations, clear textbox and increment counter
}
```

So if user presses enter while the texbox is not well formatted, nothing happens (you could prompt a message too).